# Using bootbox in RequireJS app

Tags: requirejs, bootbox

I have a sample **app.js** file with:

```
requirejs.config({
    "baseUrl": "js/lib",
    "paths": {
      "jquery": "jquery",
      "app": "../app",
      "bootstrap": "bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle",
      "bootbox": "bootbox.min"
    },
    "shim": {
        "bootstrap": {
            "deps": ["jquery"],
            "exports": 'bootbox'
             },
        "main": { "deps": ["jquery","bootstrap"] },
        "bootbox": {
            "deps": ["jquery","bootstrap"],
            "exports": 'bootbox'
        },
    }
});

require(['jquery','bootstrap','bootbox'], function($){

    $(function(jquery) {
        bootbox.alert("bla")
    });
});
```

When I run my page, I can see the correct JS files being grabbed:

[image]

...yet my code fails:

```
bootbox.alert("bla")
```

Gives:

> ReferenceError: bootbox is not defined

I must be missing something simple (again, apologies if this is a newbie error - I'm still trying to get my head around this library)

Comment: We need to stay connected to https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/24783 and see if it is really solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `shim` with Bootbox. If you look at the source code of Bootbox, you'll see it calls `define`, which registers it as a proper AMD module. The `shim` option is **only** for code which is not a proper AMD module.

Now, the `define` in Bootbox does this:

```
define(["jquery"], factory);
```

It sets a dependency on jQuery, but that is wrong, because in fact Bootbox *also* depends on Bootstrap being present. So we need to fix this. The following shows how you can fix it. You can use a `map` configuration option so that when Bootbox requires jQuery, it gets Bootstrap. And you set a `shim` for Bootstrap so that, in addition to having a dependency on jQuery, its module value is the same as jQuery (`$`).

Without the `map` setup, there's no guarantee that Bootstrap will load before Bootbox and you'll be facing a race condition: sometimes it'll work, sometimes not.

```js
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: ".",
  paths: {
    jquery: "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min",
    bootstrap: "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min",
    bootbox: "//github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/releases/download/v4.4.0/bootbox.min"
  },
  shim: {
    "bootstrap": {
      "deps": ["jquery"],
      // We set bootstrap up so that when we require it, the value with get is just $.
      // This enables the map below.
      "exports": "$"
    },
  },
  map: {
    // When bootbox requires jquery, give it bootstrap instead. This makes it so that
    // bootstrap is **necessarily** loaded before bootbox.
    bootbox: {
      jquery: "bootstrap",
    },
  }
});

require(["jquery", "bootbox"], function($, bootbox) {
  $(function(jquery) {
    bootbox.alert("bla");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.5/require.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Comment: you legend! Works like a charm :)